# "will be given access"

Tags: phrase-choice

I wonder:

1. Authorized user will be given access to this terminal as well
2. Access to authorized user will be given to this terminal as well

Which one is correct? I have heard the first phrase "user will be given access" already but I have a problem that he is not an actor but subject. If the first is correct, why?

Edit

Scenerio: new user will have access to his terminal. Other users like managers may have been granted access right too.

Comment: Neither sentence is "natural" English. What exactly do you *want* to convey? Without knowing that, we can only guess at how it might be better expressed, but my current guess is you probably want to say something like *"Authorised users will also be given access to this terminal"*. That's assuming the preceding text has already mentioned other "access rights" (not *necessarily* specifically access to "terminals", or granted to "authorised users" in particular).

Comment: That authorized users will have access rights

Comment: @ Leos: That's a start. But what's the ***as well*** part all about? Will others besides authorised users be given access to this terminal? Or will authorised users also be given something else? Perhaps access to other resources, or even things completely unrelated to access rights? You should *edit your question text* to clarify things like this.

Comment: "*Other users like managers*" would also be classified as *authorized users* so you don't have to mention them specially.

Comment: The newly-authorized user will be given access to this terminal.

Comment: What is the situation where this text will appear? Who is reading it and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one sounds much better and expresses what you mean. But the second one might be found (in speech or writing) in places whose language culture does not use or value everyday English, such as at some government installations or business facilities. Such places seem to take great joy at using befuddled English and a ton of acronyms.

However, to make it clearer, I'd say or write:

*The newly-authorized user will be given access to this terminal.*

By contrast,

*Access to the newly-authorized user will be given to this terminal* leaves speakers of everyday English to interpret the sentence to mean that the terminal will have access to the newly-authorized user!

Comment: Funny, it is exactly opposite in Czech. I feel like "to" is missing in the first sentence. To whom the access is granted.

Comment: Switch the nouns around and it is fine in English: Access to this terminal will be given to the authorized user.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would refer to the status of "authorized user" in the plural:

> Authorized **users** will be given access to this terminal as well.

The second variant looks like a confusing attempt to express the first variant ;)

Comment: The second variant is probably czenglish. Word by word translation of Czech sentence.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's any reason to say ***normally** we'd use plural here.* It's just as natural to say *"An authorized user will be given access to this terminal as well"*, and in some contexts that might well be the preferred form (though usually it wouldn't really make any difference).

Comment: "Shoplifters will be prosecuted" "Teachers are underpaid" "Experts agree" ... when we refer to a class of people, we USUALLY use the plural. I feel that in this particular case it made all the difference between a clumsy construction and a natural one.